# How can I render null value

Tags: javascript, mustache

I want to render null values when generating SQL queries, without quotes. In default behavior Mustache returns nothing for null values.
I opened already ticket with the same question with example added: https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/766.

Comment: Since a null value means, literally, *nothing*, how would you expect it to be rendered?

Comment: "I'm using mustache to generate dynamic SQL queries" This sounds like a horrible idea. Mustache is designed for HTML templating, not SQL query generation. Please use the correct tool. If you really want null to show up, `String(null)` is equal to `"null"`.

Comment: @ScottHunter same as any other value, there could be implemented some kind of switch which you can turn on when want to render null value.

Comment: @Aplet123 you can't tell not knowing context/env, about project purpose:
"Mustache is a logic-less template syntax. It can be used for HTML, config files, source code - anything. It works by expanding tags in a template using values provided in a hash or object.".

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround, converting null values to string.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var output = $("#output");    
    var template = $("#test1").html();
 
    data = {}
    data.columns = ["name", "lastname", "email"];
    data.row  = ["John", "Wick", null];
        data.values_line = function() {
        let values = this.row;
      return values.map(function(v) {
        if (typeof v === 'string') v = `'${v}'`
        if (v === null) v = "NULL"
        return v;
      })
    }
    
    var html = Mustache.render(template, data);
    output.append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/4.0.1/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Mustache example: Generate SQL query</h2>

<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="test1">
    INSERT INTO Customers({{{columns}}})<br/>
    VALUES<br/>
    ({{{values_line}}})

</script>
```